# Push footer to bottom when page is not full

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html

I'm developing a mobile web app. This is the main structure from top to bottom: header div, menu div, content div, footer div. The header, menu and footer are constant and pages are loaded into the content div using ajax.

Some of the pages have lots of content and they fill out the page so scroll is needed. Some of the pages have only one or two lines of content so they leave a big empty part (Not necessarily different pages - one page for example shows a list of orders, you can have no orders and you can have hundreds...).

This is what i want to achieve: If the page is not full with content, the footer will be in the bottom of the page. If the page is full and scroll is needed, the footer will be immediately after the content (so you scroll down the page and in the end you reach the footer).

The sticky footer solutions are not good for me because i don't want the footer to stick to the bottom always, only when the page is not full of content.

Is there anyway to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: With jQuery or vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 26):

Then you have to use javascript for that - calculate the height of the content - substract it from the window height and set the margin-top of the footer from that distance:

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4k4j/4/)
- [jsfiddle show](http://jsfiddle.net/g4k4j/4/show/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header" class="header">Header</div>
<div id="content" class="content">Content</div>
<div id="footer" class="footer">Footer</div>
```

**JS** (This example uses jQuery, it should be included before this script.)

```
$('#footer').css('margin-top',
  $(document).height() 
  - ( $('#header').height() + $('#content').height() ) 
  - $('#footer').height()
);
```

You can put an onresize window that call this function on any resize of the window.

**[edit blag :]**

Here is the **onResize** method (but with a `min-height` and not a `margin-top`)

[Check the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4k4j/69/)

```
 // function to set the height on fly
 function autoHeight() {
   $('#content').css('min-height', 0);
   $('#content').css('min-height', (
     $(document).height() 
     - $('#header').height() 
     - $('#footer').height()
   ));
 }

 // onDocumentReady function bind
 $(document).ready(function() {
   autoHeight();
 });

 // onResize bind of the function
 $(window).resize(function() {
   autoHeight();
 });
```

---

**Borders, padding and margin**

If you want to have borders and padding included in the calculation you can use `outerHeight()` instead of `height()`. Alternatively `outerHeight(true)` also includes margins.

Comment: Thanks, Very good but not work when add window resize event. You can see that in fork of of your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jnLp5x7u/

Answer (score 3):

A CSS Sticky footer should solve your problem.

[Here's an example](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

That is super easy to setup and use. It will force the footer down the page with the content, and if the content isn't big enough to fill the page it will stick to the bottom.

Comment: The sticky footer is not good for me because in cases where i have content that is longer than a page i want the footer to appear only after scrolling all the way down. The jquery solution look good and I'm trying it. Thank you all :)

Comment: Thanks for this, the flexbox option worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution i came to on my project

```
function autoHeight() {

    if ( document.body.clientHeight < window.innerHeight ) {
        document.querySelector('#footer').style.position = 'absolute';
        document.querySelector('#footer').style.bottom = '0';
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  autoHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function autoHeight() {
        var h = $(document).height() - $('body').height();
        if (h > 0) {
            $('#footer').css({
                marginTop: h
            });
        }
    }
    $(window).on('load', autoHeight);
```

Comment: Rather than only posting code, please describe why you think this is a solution, so that others have some context and further insight regarding your answer.  Please see here for [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, i'll try next time :)

Comment: You should try *this time*, by [edit]ing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for me, based on the answer from Александр Михайлов.  It finds the bottom of the footer and determines if it is less than the document height and uses top margin on the footer to make up the shortfall. This solution might give issues if your content is being resized on the go.

```
$(function () {
    updateFooterPosition();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    updateFooterPosition();
});

function updateFooterPosition() {
    var bottomOfFooter = $('footer').offset().top + $('footer').outerHeight(true);
    var heightShortage = $(document).height() - bottomOfFooter;
    if (heightShortage < 0) heightShortage = 0;
    $('footer').css('margin-top', heightShortage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. I think this is perfect if you have more than only a #header and #footer. It just push the content down with a padding-bottom if body is smaller than the viewport.

```
function autoHeight() {
    var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
    var vwptHeight = $(window).height();
    var gap = vwptHeight - bodyHeight;
    if (vwptHeight > bodyHeight) {
        $("#content").css( "padding-bottom" , gap );
    } else {
        $("#content").css( "padding-bottom" , "0" );
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    autoHeight();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    autoHeight();   
});
```